# excel format date for mysql

Tags: mysql, excel

My excel sheet has the following format : **dd/mm/YYYY**

ex: 24/10/2010 (european format)

and my mysql needs: **YYYY-mm-dd** (US format)

How can I format the date in Excel to have this US format ?
I tried with cell format, but I don't have the desired format

Regards

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD is the ISO 8601 format, not the US format.

Answer (score 17):

Here's how you can find this Number format in Excel:

1. Go to **Format Cells** and then the **Number** tab.
2. Select **Date**
3. Change the Locale to **English (U.K.)**
4. The fifth item on the list (on my U.S. version of Excel) is the format you're looking for.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 16):

For the hours, minutes and second

go in the custom category and enter this :

yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 7):

Use the text function -- assuming that the date to be converted was in cell A1, =TEXT(A1,"YYYYMMDD") will get your data into a format that mysql will understand as a date.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions, but I reformat the dates for mysql using this formula (assuming your date is in cell E2):

```
=YEAR(E2)&"-"&RIGHT(TRIM(100+MONTH(E2)),2)&"-"&RIGHT(TRIM(100+DAY(E2)),2)
```